# Insert into JSON array from HTML form

Tags: angularjs

I have an HTML form with the following fields: *Note Type* (as a combobox), *Note Author*: (as a textbox), and *Note Description* (as a textarea). This HTML form is written inside an *AngularJS* service in a variable and then displayed.

On click of the *Save Note* button, I need this information to be sent to a JSON array stored in another *JavaScript* file, which in turn, is displayed on a table as a list of notes.

The JSON array must be in the following form after say, two notes are added:

```
var noteData = [
{
    "NoteType": "Type1",
    "NoteAuthor": "John Doe",
    "NoteDescription": "My first note."
 },
 {
    "NoteType": "Type2",
    "NoteAuthor": "Peter Doe",
    "NoteDescription": "My second note."
 } ];
```

How do I go about doing this?

My HTML form inside the *AngularJS* service looks like this:

```html
var addNoteSection = '<label>Note Type: </label><br />' + 
'<select ng-model="myModel.NoteType"><option value="Type 1">Type 1</option><option value="Type 2">Type 2</option>' +
'<label>Note Author: </label><br /><input type="text" ng-model="myModel.NoteCreator" /><br />' +
'<label>Note Description: </label><br /><textarea ng-model="myModel.NoteDescription" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br />' +
'<button ng-click="saveNewNote()">Save Note</button>'
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
  
  $scope.noteData=[];
  $scope.myModel = {
       "NoteType": "",
       "NoteCreator":"",
       "NoteDescription":""
    };
  $scope.saveNewNote = function(model){
    var item = {
       "NoteType": model.NoteType,
       "NoteCreator": model.NoteCreator,
       "NoteDescription": model.NoteDescription
     };
    
     $scope.noteData.push(item);
     console.log($scope.noteData);
    };
  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
     <label>Note Type: </label><br />
     <select ng-model="myModel.NoteType">
        <option value="Type 1">Type 1</option>
        <option value="Type 2">Type2</option>
      </select>
     <label>Note Author: </label><br />
       <input type="text" ng-model="myModel.NoteCreator" /><br />
   <label>Note Description: </label><br />
   <textarea ng-model="myModel.NoteDescription" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br />
    
     <button ng-click="saveNewNote(myModel)">Save Note</button>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

$scope.saveNewNote = function() { noteData.push($scope.myModel); }